# IndexError when accessing list elements

Tags: python, string, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to extract values from a list (saved in the file 'Verhaltens_Baum_Read'). See below its first 4 lines:

```
['Possibilities', 'Condition', 'Gen', 'Insight', 'False', 'Solved', 'OldNew', 'RemKnow']  
['1', 'Exp', 'Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'New', 'Ka']  
['2', 'Base', 'Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'New', 'Ka']  
['3', 'Exp', 'Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'Old', 'Remember']
```

For so, I wrote this code:

```
Condition_Names = open('Condition_Names.txt','w')

file = open('Verhaltens_Baum_Read.txt','r')

for splitted in file:
    if splitted[1] == 'Exp':
        Condition_Names.write('Exp_')
    if splitted[1] == 'Base':
        Condition_Names.write('Base_')
    if splitted[2] == 'Erkannt':
        Condition_Names.write('Gen_')
    if splitted[2] == 'Nicht Erkannt':
        Condition_Names.write('NotGen_')    
    if splitted[3] == 'AHA':
        Condition_Names.write('Aha_')
    if splitted[3] == 'Kein AHA':
        Condition_Names.write('NoAha_')
    if splitted[4] == ('Real'):
        Condition_Names.write('Real_')
    if splitted[4] == ('False'):
        Condition_Names.write('False_')
    if splitted[5] == ('Yes 1'):          #This is the line 27
        Condition_Names.write('Solved_')
    if splitted[5] == ('No 0'):
        Condition_Names.write('NotSolved_')
    if splitted[6] == 'Old':
        Condition_Names.write('Old_')
    if splitted[6] == 'New':
        Condition_Names.write('New_')
    if splitted[7] == 'Ka':
        Condition_Names.write('Ka\n')
    if splitted[7] == 'Remember':
        Condition_Names.write('Rem\n')
    if splitted[7] == 'Recognized':
        Condition_Names.write('Recog\n')
```

and then I want my code to write names in another text file according to the occurrences on the list. The output to my code is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Condition_Names_Generate.py", line 27, in <module>
    if splitted[5] == ('Yes 1'):
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I really cannot understand why it happens. The splitted[5] item was saved as a string on the list, as you can see it above. I would appreciate any help.

The exact contents of Verhaltens_Baum.txt are the following:

```
['Possibilities', 'Condition', 'Gen', 'Insight', 'False', 'Solved', 'OldNew', 'RemKnow']
['1', 'Exp', 'Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'New', 'Ka']
['2', 'Base', 'Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'New', 'Ka']
['3', 'Exp', 'Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'Old', 'Remember']
['4', 'Base', 'Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'Old', 'Remember']
['5', 'Exp', 'Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'Old', 'Recognized']
['6', 'Base', 'Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'Old', 'Recognized']
['7', 'Exp', 'Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'New', 'Ka']
['8', 'Base', 'Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'New', 'Ka']
['9', 'Exp', 'Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'Old', 'Remember']
['10', 'Base', 'Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'Old', 'Remember']
['11', 'Exp', 'Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'Old', 'Recognized']
['12', 'Base', 'Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'Old', 'Recognized']
['13', 'Exp', 'Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'New', 'Ka']
['14', 'Base', 'Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'New', 'Ka']
['15', 'Exp', 'Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'Old', 'Remember']
['16', 'Base', 'Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'Old', 'Remember']
['17', 'Exp', 'Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'Old', 'Recognized']
['18', 'Base', 'Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'Old', 'Recognized']
['19', 'Exp', 'Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'New', 'Ka']
['20', 'Base', 'Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'New', 'Ka']
['21', 'Exp', 'Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'Old', 'Remember']
['22', 'Base', 'Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'Old', 'Remember']
['23', 'Exp', 'Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'Old', 'Recognized']
['24', 'Base', 'Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'Old', 'Recognized']
['25', 'Exp', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'New', 'Ka']
['26', 'Base', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'New', 'Ka']
['27', 'Exp', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'Old', 'Remember']
['28', 'Base', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'Old', 'Remember']
['29', 'Exp', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'Old', 'Recognized']
['30', 'Base', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'Old', 'Recognized']
['31', 'Exp', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'New', 'Ka']
['32', 'Base', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'New', 'Ka']
['33', 'Exp', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'Old', 'Remember']
['34', 'Base', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'Old', 'Remember']
['35', 'Exp', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'Old', 'Recognized']
['36', 'Base', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'Old', 'Recognized']
['37', 'Exp', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'New', 'Ka']
['38', 'Base', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'New', 'Ka']
['39', 'Exp', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'Old', 'Remember']
['40', 'Base', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'Old', 'Remember']
['41', 'Exp', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'Old', 'Recognized']
['42', 'Base', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'Yes 1', 'Old', 'Recognized']
['43', 'Exp', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'New', 'Ka']
['44', 'Base', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'New', 'Ka']
['45', 'Exp', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'Old', 'Remember']
['46', 'Base', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'Old', 'Remember']
['47', 'Exp', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'Old', 'Recognized']
['48', 'Base', 'Nicht Erkannt', 'Kein AHA', 'Real', 'No 0', 'Old', 'Recognized']
['49', '', '', '', 'False', 'Yes 1', 'New', 'Ka']
['50', '', '', '', 'False', 'Yes 1', 'Old', 'Remember']
['51', '', '', '', 'False', 'Yes 1', 'Old', 'Recognized']
['52', '', '', '', 'False', 'No 0', 'New', 'Ka']
['53', '', '', '', 'False', 'No 0', 'Old', 'Remember']
['54', '', '', '', 'False', 'No 0', 'Old', 'Recognized']
['']
```

Comment: what is your desired output to be written to the file?

Comment: @Ajax1234 I want the code to generate a text file with a name on each line.
The names should be comprise by words like "Solved_", "NotSolved_" etc... according to the if statement condition. For example, the first if statement stablishes how should the name begin. If there is an "Exp" on the list, "Exp_" should be written on a file. If there is "Yes 1" on the list, "Solved_" should be written as the fifth part of the name and so on.

Comment: you are not splitting the line you are reading into a list at any point. Note that the error says "string Iindex", not "list index", so you are operating on Strings, not lists. use `split()` to separate the string you read in into a list ([tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm)), then take it from there

Comment: if you can copy and paste the *exact contents* of Verhaltens_Baum_Read.txt here, we'll be able to help you

Comment: I have found the solution. As I generated the Verhaltens_Baum.txt copying and pasting it from an Excel sheet, some cells were blank and therefore the list items were also lacking. I don't know why it happened, but since I've substitued the empty cells by 'NoData' it started to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want write in the new file, but to verify your list you can make this

```
Condition_Names = open('Condition_Names.txt','w')
with open('Verhaltens_Baum_Read.txt', 'r') as file: # this make file a obj with information of your .txt, after that you can work with him, and after end the identification block the file close and save
    for splitted in file:
        #here you can verify word by word, using splitted[0] etc.

Condition_Names.close()
```

I recommend you change the name of variables, start with lower case, like conditionNames maybe.